# Notation: What does $\bf{Z}^*_R$ mean in the context of groups?

Tags: group-theory, notation

I recently stumbled upon the following definition for a hash function:

> To get this we define $\hat{h}=\hat{h}_{r}: {\{0,1\}}^* \rightarrow {\bf Z}_R$ 
>   as follows:
>   $$ \hat{h}_r(m) = ({\sum_{i=1}^{k} m_i \cdot r^{i-1}}) \bmod R $$
>   where $R$ is a 161-bit prime, $r$ (the key of $\hat{h}$) is a uniformly distributed 
>   element in ${\bf Z}_{R}^*, [...]$

Source: http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~naor/p_r_func/pr/pr.html

As far as I understand, $\textbf{Z}_R$ is the additive group of integers $\mod R$. Is this the case?

If so, then what is $\textbf{Z}^*_R$?

Comment: It's the group of invertibles of $\mathbb{Z}_R$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_(ring_theory) In case when $R$ is prime it is simply $\mathbb{Z}_R\backslash\{0\}$.

Comment: Thank you, that answered the question :)

Comment: It's a theorem that $\mathbf{Z}_R^*$ is cyclic if $R$ is prime. (This is often exploited by simple random number generators - see Knuth, *The Art of Computer Programming*, Vol.2?.)